# IFAB: Technical Area, Substitutes

Tags: rules, football

I was learning Laws of the Game from IFAB  [official website](http://www.theifab.com/laws) and have a question about the technical area.

In the [Laws](http://www.theifab.com/laws/the-field-of-play/chapters/the-technical-area), it states as follows:

> #### 9. Technical Area
>
> ...
>
> the occupants of the technical area:
>
> - are identified before the start of the match in accordance with the competition rules
> - must behave in a responsible manner
> - *must remain within its confines except in specific circumstances, e.g. physiotherapist/doctor entering the field of play, with the referee’s permission, to assess an injured player*

Look at the third item in italic font. I don't see it clearly states about substitutes. I see substitution players do warm-up during the match, in the area along the touchlines outside of the technical one. Is anything mentioned about this clearly in other chapters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't found anything mentioning warming up of substitutes in official rules of FIFA ([new](http://www.theifab.com/laws/the-field-of-play/chapters/the-technical-area), [old](https://www.fifa.com/mm/document/affederation/generic/81/42/36/lawsofthegame_2011_12e.pdf)), however I was able to find this in competition specific rules like [UEFA Champions League](http://www.uefa.com/uefachampionsleague/#/), [Carabao Cup (EFL)](https://www.efl.com/clubs-and-competitions/carabao-cup/), etc.

*[Regulations of the UEFA Champions League 2017/18](https://www.uefa.com/MultimediaFiles/Download/Regulations/uefaorg/Regulations/02/46/71/38/2467138_DOWNLOAD.pdf)*:

> Article 41 Rules governing the technical area
>
> 41.03 **During the match, substitutes are allowed to leave the technical area to warm up**.
> The referee determines exactly where they may warm up (behind the first
> assistant referee or behind the advertising boards behind the goal) and how many
> substitutes are allowed to warm up simultaneously. In principle, three substitutes
> per team are allowed to warm up at the same time; exceptionally, if space so
> permits, the referee can allow up to seven substitutes of each team to warm up
> simultaneously in the determined area. The team fitness coach (indicated on the
> match sheet) may join the players warming up and is responsible for the respect
> of the referee’s instructions.

*[Carabao Cup Rules & Regulations](https://www.efl.com/clubs-and-competitions/carabao-cup/about-the-carabao-cup/carabao-cup-rules--regulations/)*:

> 10 Substitutes
>
> 10.3 All substitutes must be nominated and included on the official Team Sheet handed to the Referee prior to the match. **Not more than three substitutes of each Club may warm up or down at the same time on the perimeter of the pitch on which the match is being played.**

Which shows that this rule is specific to different competitions. So, *[substitutes may warm up along the side of the pitch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_area#cite_note-FIFALaws-1)* as per the regulation of a competitions.